# Determination of dead time of a Geiger-Muller counter using the two source method

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

While determining the dead time of a GM counter using the two source method, why do we ensure that only two sources are placed in the counter at all times i.e. while determining the counts when both the sources are placed, why don't we place the dummies along with them?

Answer (score 1):

When the counts from two sources are measured, the recorded counts express the actual counts produced from each source (lets call them a + b)  plus the counts produced from scattering due to the presence of the physical structure of the neighboring source (let's call them a' + b'). So total recorded counts with two sources would be (a + a' + b + b').

Now for a single active source without any other sources placed around, the recorded counts would be only (a) without (a') that was due to the presence of a neighboring physical structure which will be inconsistent with previously counted (a + a') due to this source alone. The solution is to use a "dummy source" (a source with the same physical structure but without nuclear activity) and place it while recording counts from the single active source.

As you can see from the above, while using two active sources, no need for placing dummies because each of the two active sources act like the dummy for the other (emits for itself and scatter for the other).